# insurance on foreign cars covers any driver?

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance

I'm driving my car, registered in Romania, in the UK (I'm not a resident). If I'm lending it to another Romanian and he will be stoped by the police, will they see him like an insured driver or not? In Romania, the insurance is for the car and not for the driver as in the UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [relevant page from europa.eu](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/insurance/validity/tourist_en.htm)

> Your car insurance policy from your home country covers you throughout the EU if you injure someone.
>
> Your car's number plate is proof that you have liability insurance. This means that police in another country will not normally stop you just to check if you are insured.

So this means:

1. Police should not stop him only to check whether he is insured or not (if he is stopped it will usually be to check whether he is a resident or not)
2. He is covered by the insurance in your home country. If that insurance policy allows others to drive the car, then he will also be insured.

Comment: As an additional comment EU rules also say that a foreign EU insurance also has to insure the car and the driver in foreign EU countries at the minimal level that is necessarry in the other country, which might be a higher in some regards than it is originally insured in the home country. IANAL, but this might mean that a UK insured car could potentially be driven by other people in EU countries where the minium insurance level is to have a car insured for *any* driver (like in Hungary or Romania)

Answer (score 1):

The question really is "Is he insured?". If the insurance policy says yes then he is - the worst that could happen is a long conversation with the police to explain this.

UK-issued insurance policies are typically long documents with complicated exclusions around number of consecutive days you can take your car abroad. If your Romanian-issued  policy is similarly complicated then you should check it very carefully. 
If he has an accident in your car and the insurer refuses to pay you may be without a car and he may be personally liable to pay damages and/or face a criminal charge.